# How to customize the captured camera image to my image view size

Tags: android

How can i fix the captured image to the image view to the layout so that it can able to see in the fine way in is shown  in the cropped way so that the image view is getting slow help me out......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read more about Scale types of ImageView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html.
It may help you.

Comment: But i want to fill the whole image view with the several small images so that i can make a new image with it